# Tkinter in python: Unresolved reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so im making a simple log in and sign up page and all is going well until i try to get my variables from my definition for my sign up page. Python says it is an unresolved reference that should resolve the typing matches and all but maybe somebody can help. Also i know there is a easier way to add pages by using classes but i i decided to do it this way. Thanks ahead of time. p.s the error is in the sign_up_check() code which the variables are gotten from the sign_up() definition.

```
import tkinter

# window set up

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("300x200")
window.title("Game")
window.configure(bg="grey26")

# username label

lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="username", bg="gold")
enter_username = tkinter.Entry(window, bg="indian red1")
lbl.pack()
enter_username.pack()

# password setup

label_password = tkinter.Label(window, text="password", bg="gold")
enter_password = tkinter.Entry(window, bg="indian red1")
label_password.pack()
enter_password.pack()


# sign in


def log_in():
    username = enter_username.get()
    password = enter_password.get()
    if len(username) > 0 and len(password) > 0:
        print("it passed")
    else:
        print("Log in error: Double check username and password")


def sign_up_check():
    # init vars
    username = signup_username.get()
    password = signup_pasword.get()
    age = signup_age.get()
    # check if vars greater than one
    if len(username) > 0 and len(password) > 0 and age > 0:
        print("this all passed")
    else:
        print("all else failed")


def sign_up():
    # create new window

    window1 = tkinter.Toplevel()
    window1.geometry("300x200")
    window1.title("Sign up")
    window1.configure(bg="grey26")
    # create buttons and labels

    # username
    label_sign_up = tkinter.Label(window1, text="Enter new username", bg="indian red1")
    signup_username = tkinter.Entry(window1, bg="gold")
    label_sign_up.pack()
    signup_username.pack()

    # password
    label_sign_up_password = tkinter.Label(window1, text="Enter new password", bg="indian red1")
    signup_password = tkinter.Entry(window1, bg="gold")
    label_sign_up_password.pack()
    signup_password.pack()

    # age
    label_enter_age = tkinter.Label(window1, text="Enter your age", bg="indian red1")
    signup_age = tkinter.Entry(window1, bg="gold")
    label_enter_age.pack()
    signup_age.pack()

    # confirm account
    button_account = tkinter.Button(window1, text="Create account", bg="red", command=lambda: sign_up_check())
    button_account.pack()


# log in button set up

button_login = tkinter.Button(window, text="Log in", bg="gold", command=lambda: log_in())
button_login.pack()

# sign up button


button_signup = tkinter.Button(window, text="Sign up", bg="gold", command=lambda: sign_up())
button_signup.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: For one thing in `sign_up_check()` you have `password = signup_pasword.get()` instead of `password = signup_password.get()`. Even if you fix that, `signup_password` is a local variable defined in the `sign_up()` function (which cannot be referenced outside of it and will vanish as soon as the function returns). To avoid the problem you should use classes (or global variables which is what many folks do to get around it).

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for your behavior is that the locally defined variables from your functions are in a local scope.
That means that they are only available in your local function, not outside of it.

Like martineau pointed out, you have a typo in password in function `sign_up_check`.

Using global Variables:

- to make this work every widget that is created inside a function needs to be created globally.

```
    def login():
        global enter_username, enter_password
        # [... The rest of the code ...]
    def sign_up_check():
        global signup_username, signup_password, signup_age
        # [... The rest of the code ...]
```

Is there any specific and programmatically relevant reason why you do not want to use classes?

To be honest with you, i do not see any advantage in using global variables and procedural programming in coding Graphical User Interfaces especially with python.

I highly recommend an object oriented programming style here to improve maintenance of code and reduce the amount of redundant coding (global declaration at beginning, global usage in every function, etc...).

Comment: @RAPH43L Can you elaborate on this?  GUI's tend to be all about side effects; I would have thought the functional style a bad match.  I always think of GUI's as  the place where OOP really shines.  I'd really like to see an example in the functional style.  Can you post a link or something?

Comment: @saulspatz I am not really sure where you read my answer as "functional style is good for GUI" - no offense intended. I meant to point out that OOP is the "better" way of coding GUIs, and that functional is an approach that lacks many things and includes bad habits like redundant code, a mess to maintain, etc.. 
I do not know any example but simple testing / experimenting where functional can be of good use for GUIs

Comment: You're right.  I don't know how I misread it either.  I'm recovering from an attack of vertigo; perhaps that explains it.  I thought my mental acuity had returned to normal, but apparently not.  Apologies.

Comment: You do not have to apologise for that :) no offense  taken here ;)